# Missing wayland headers files

Tags: linux, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, wayland, qtwayland

The error I'm getting:
error: gst/wayland/wayland.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../QtService/videooverlay.cpp:1:
../QtService/videooverlay.h:11:10: fatal error: gst/wayland/wayland.h: No such file or directory
11 | #include <gst/wayland/wayland.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I reinstalled the library libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev but this also seems to be not working for me.

Comment: Which distribution are you using? Try to find if the header file is present in your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this error in WSL configuration is:

Check the version of ubuntu using (cat  /etc/lsb-release) this command. If the version is 20 then install the ubuntu version 22.04.

If your ubuntu version is 22.04 then reinstall the gsteamer lib package completely fresh or upgrade/update the gstreamer lib.

Let me know if anyone needs help in Linux command for these.